# list container on stack and accessed in other function

Tags: c++, std

I am confused about storing the list container allocated on stack, and accessing the stored list container in some other function. Please suggest if it's better to put everything on heap ? Putting everything on heap will require more careful delete operation in the destructor.

```
typedef (*func)(); // Callback type  

class SignalHandler {
    ...
    ...
    void Register(int, func);
    void UnRegister(int, func);


public:
    map<int, list<func> > mCallbackMap;
}


void SignalHandler::Register(int signal, func f){
....
    list<func> l;   // A new list 
    l.push_back(f);  // insert f to the list
    mCallbackMap.insert(make_pair(signal, l)); // Insert in map
....
....
....
}
```

In the function Register, list l, the list container will be allocated on the stack. This container is inserted into the map. As the container is allocated on the stack, will be safe to access the list container stored in map in some other function?

For example:

```
void SignalHandler::UnRegister(int signal, func f) {
....
....
    it = mCallbackMap.find(signal);
    if (it != mCallbackMap.end()) {
        list<func> *l = &(it->second);   // Is it OK to access it here? I am confused. 
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

STL containers follow Value semantics and not Reference Semantics. So they actually create internal copies of their elements and return copies of those elements. Since copies are created, you should be fine.

Comment: I guess you are pointing towards the use of copy constructor. Makes sense. Thanks!!